# gpupdate causes flickering in some programs

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-10

We have an issue with GPOs during *gpupdate*. When a group policy is processed, which adds a net share, then e.g. the calendar side pane in Outlook starts to flicker. Also an other application which we're using for accounting flickers a lot at that time.
We're using Windows 10 and Domain Controllers are running on Windows Server 2012

It happens if I run `gpupdate` with a user who has group policy settings for:
1. adding, updating, or creating net shares 
2. running registry settings

Other group policy settings does not lead to flickering.

There is nothing logged in the *eventvwr.msc* at the time of the flickering, except the *gpupdate* logs.
I don't think it is a display driver problem either, because on we have the exact same problem on multiple hardware.

Are there any suggestions, what the problem could be and what I could investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the flickering is default behaviour during GPO update.
The only way is to increase the GPO update refresh interval:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396